# HttpWebRequest times out if Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is changed

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, timeout, cultureinfo

If you change Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to something different than installed (OS culture), the call to HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() will always time out.

Just for clarification, here's contents of my utility class that is doing the dirty work:

```
private static void ReplicateCookies(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        return;
    if (request.CookieContainer == null)
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    foreach (var cookie in from object key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Keys select HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key.ToString()])
        request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Domain) 
            ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
            : cookie.Domain));
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method = null)
{
    var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    ReplicateCookies(httpRequest);
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    httpRequest.Method = method ?? "GET";
    httpRequest.Timeout = 20000;
    httpRequest.Proxy = null;
    httpRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 20000;
    httpRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 10000;
    return httpRequest;
}

public string ReadWebPage(string url)
{
    var oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    string result;
    var httpRequest = CreateRequest(url);
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", oldCulture);
    try
    {
        using (var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            }
            httpResponse.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        httpRequest.Abort();
    }
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(oldCulture);
    return result;
}
```

In case you're wondering:

- in ReplicateCookies, if you call CookieCOntainer.Add with null as domain it fails in runtime
- the code already contains a fix that gets around the CurrentCulture issue. Go on, take out all the code that is changing the culture, set your thread culture to something (for example "fr-FR") and give the code a spin.

I've made sure that:

- no proxy is interfering with request
- no firewall settings prevent requests like this

Perhaps it's worth mentioning that this was used inside a MVC3 web application internally to generate templated messages - where a template is a web page itself. The application sets it's culture like this (Global.asax.cs):

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        return;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
        return;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"] != null)
        CultureHelper.SetCulture(HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"].ToString());
}
```

And the helper class:

```
public static class CultureHelper
{
    public static void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
            return;
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
        if (culture.ToLower().Equals("fr-fr") || culture.ToLower().Equals("fr"))
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
}
```

French by default uses space as thousands delimiter for some reason - thus the if statement.

The ReplicateCookies method will copy session cookie and authentication cookie to the internal request so the session / authentication is preserved in resulting internal request.

The site obviously has means to change the current culture (change session value). Prior to the fix in ReadWebPage method everything would work fine until culture was changed. After that every HttpWebRequest.GetResponse would time out until culture was changed back to - in my case - en-GB.

Any ideas why this is happening? I could be doing something grossly wrong somewhere. As I said it's working in it's current state. It's just not very pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Since all attempts to quickly delete this post before anyone sees it failed, here's the solution. As usual it was that one thing you never think of - session. While I draw the "Smash your head here!" black dot on a piece of paper, here's the corrected code:

```
private static void ReplicateCookies(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        return;
    if (request.CookieContainer == null)
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    foreach (var cookieKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Keys)
    {
        if (!cookieKey.ToString().Equals("ASP.NET_SessionId"))
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieKey.ToString()];
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Domain)
                ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
                : cookie.Domain));
        }

    }
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method = null)
{
    var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    ReplicateCookies(httpRequest);
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    httpRequest.Method = method ?? "GET";
    httpRequest.Timeout = 20000;
    httpRequest.Proxy = null;
    httpRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 20000;
    httpRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 10000;
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    return httpRequest;
}

public string ReadWebPage(string url)
{
    string result;
    var httpRequest = CreateRequest(url);
    try
    {
        using (var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            }
            httpResponse.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        httpRequest.Abort();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Explanation: the issue was in ReplicateCookies method. Among everything else it was rewriting the ASP session cookie. And since it was making a call to the same process the later hang (and eventually timed out) because the session from initial request was locked - and the incoming request was trying to use the same session.

Now off to hang this big black dot of a head magnet on the wall ...